# How to do AJAX login in Cakephp 2.8.0?

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.8

I have done simple login in Cakephp using authcomponent, it really works fine, how can I do login using ajax?

I have use code for simple login that are given below:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) 
{
    if ($this->Auth->login()) 
    {
        if ($this->Auth->user('role') === 'admin') 
        {

            $this->redirect(array('admin' => false,'controller' => 'users','action' => 'index'));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you would need some JavaScript to send credentials and a JSON response to say whether it was successful or not. You can do this with raw JavaScript, or use a library like jQuery. You can then use a controller to give the correct responses.

Comment: sir, i have using $.ajax jquery method but problem is that how can compare it

Comment: OK, please add your JS code. I would assume you are sending username, password and role from your JavaScript. You will probably need another controller for this - use the above PHP logic and return a JSON response with a success boolean and error strings as required.

Comment: sir i want to say that how can compare value that is sended through ajax in $this->Auth->login() method also my password is stored in hash format,it is uses blowfish for hashing,so i convert password in blowfish using this method      $hash = Security::hash($this->request->data['User']['password'], 'blowfish',$savepass); but it hash password differently every time,please help

Comment: I've no idea, since I don't use CakePHP. I've done a quick search in the manual, [and found this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-stateless-authentication-systems) - you can search for a user based on a username and password combo.

Comment: post your login.ctp file ?? if that all good without ajax , wouldn't be hard with ajax as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax code should be like this :

```
$(document).on('submit','#yourFormId',function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var data = $(this).serialize();
   var url = 'url_for_your_login_method'; /* like 'localhost/your_project_name/Users/login' */
   $.ajax({
     url:url,
     type:'post',
     data:data,
     dataType:'json',
     success:function(response) {
       if(response == 1) {
        // login success
       } else {
        // login fails
        }
     }
   });
});
```

And in your login method should be like this:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) 
{
if ($this->Auth->login()) 
  {
     if ($this->Auth->user('role') === 'admin') 
      {
         $output = 1; // login success and role is admin
      } else {
         $output = 0; // login success but role is not admin
      }
   } else {
         $output = 2; // login fails
     }
    $this->set(array(
        'output'=>$output,
        '_serialize'=>'output'
     ));
}
```

For Blowfish password hash,
In your AppController:

```
  <?php
 class AppController {

  public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
            )
          )
       )
     );
   }
  ?>
```

And in AppModel:

```
 <?php
   App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');


    class User extends AppModel {

      public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
      // if ID is not set, we're inserting a new user as opposed to updating
          $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
          $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
      return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello HOw can convert password in blowfish,because we have use ajax method,so cakephp not automatically convert it oon blowfish,please suggest me....

Comment: check ajax response in console.

Comment: i have use this but it always return 'no'                            if ($this->request->is('ajax')) 
      {
         $this->layout='ajax';
         $this->autoRender=false;
         
        if ($this->Auth->login()) 
        {
          echo 'yes';

        }
        else
        {

          echo 'no';
        }

      }

Comment: your request type is post , so check if($this->request->is('post')).